# Unit testing with aws-cdk typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, aws-cdk

I am very new to aws-cdk and have created a stack to which consists of a kinesis firehose , elastic search , lambda , S3 bucket and a few roles as per requirement. Now I want to test my code locally. I was able to get a few samples but they don't have clearly mentioned how to run the unit test cases

```
module.exports = {
    'default bucket'(test) {
        const stack = new cdk.Stack();
        new s3.Bucket(stack, 'MyBucket');
        assert_1.expect(stack).toMatch({
            "Resources": {
                "MyBucketF68F3FF0": {
                    "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
                    "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
                    "UpdateReplacePolicy": "Retain",
                }
            }
        });
        test.done();
    }
};
```

It would be great if I could get a proper example of how to run a unit test using aws-cdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it with help of jest ref link https://garbe.io/blog/2019/03/26/construct-your-own-cdk-construct-library/